# Using Synergy Pro 1.8.8, but clicks are not working on Client

Tags: synergy

Windows 10 as the server and MacOS 10.13 as Client.

The client (macOS) is getting connected to the server. I can even see the mouse cursor. But the client is not accepting the clicks (Left or Right). The keyboard input works fine. I really don't understand the problem. Tried restarting both the host and the client and still, the problem persists.

Comment: It can be a bug or hardware issue.Have you tried keyboard shortcut for right click??.You can activate that from preferences.Search for mouse keys activiate it and press control+keypad's 5 key.

Comment: If you are using a logitech mouse, with the logitech options software, the problem lies with the software. In my experience, closing the software on the server via the task manager will fix the mouse not clicking.